# PHP Comparing 0 does not work

Tags: php, loops, comparison

I'm trying to set a checkbox as checked in php based on an hour fields from a comma separated value string. It works well for  1-23 but for some reason hour 0 always displays as checked:

```
<?php
myhours = explode(",", substr($arruser['arhours'],0,strlen($arruser['arhours']) - 1));
$checked = "";
for($hour = 0; $hour <= 23; $hour++) {
    if(count($myhours) > 0) {
        for($h = 0; $h <= count($myhours); $h++) {
            if((int)$hour == (int)$myhours[$h]) {
                $checked = " checked ";
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $checked = "";  
    }
    if(strlen($hour) == 1) {
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox " . $checked . " value=" . $hour . " onchange=\"updatehour(" . $_REQUEST['user'] . ",this.checked, '" . $hour . "')\">0$hour:00</td>";   
    } else {
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox " . $checked . " value=" . $hour . " onchange=\"updatehour(" . $_REQUEST['user'] . ",this.checked, '" . $hour . "')\">$hour:00</td>";
    }
    $checked = "";
}
?>
```

Comment: $myhours is not an array array format is like $myhours = array(10,14,20,22); then it will give you the count of array otherwise it give the length of string

Comment: Modified question as `$myhours` come from a string in database and then I use the `explode` function.

Comment: Modified question as that is exactly how I am getting $myhours.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your error though but should not it be for($h = 0; $h < count($myhours); $h++)  instead of for($h = 0; $h <= count($myhours); $h++) since items go from 0 to length - 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is straightforward; look at the outer loop:

```
for ($hour = 0; $hour <= 23; $hour++) {
```

Consider only the first iteration, so `$hour` is `int(0)`. Further in the code:

```
if(count($myhours) > 0) {
    for($h = 0; $h <= count($myhours); $h++) {
```

Pay close attention to the loop condition:

```
$h <= count($myhours)
```

Consider the last iteration of that loop, so `$h` equals the size of your array.

```
if ((int)$hour == (int)$myhours[$h]) {
```

At this point `$myhours[$h]` is undefined because the array index is out of bounds (and a notice would have been emitted) and so `(int)$myhours[$h]` becomes `(int)null` which is `int(0)`. The comparison is therefore always true when `$hour` has the value of `int(0)`.

The solution is to change the loop condition to:

```
$h < count($myhours)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly and answer, but your code could be reduced to this:

```
$myhours = array(0, 10, 13, 20);
for($hour = 0; $hour <= 23; $hour++) {
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox"' . ( in_array($hour, $myhours) ? ' checked' : '' ) . ' value="' . $hour . '" onchange="updatehour(' . $_REQUEST['user'] . ', this.checked, ' . $hour . ')">' . str_pad($hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':00</td>';   
}
```

No need for a second loop and more variables here. Also be aware to not output values from `$_REQUEST` directly without any check.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepad.org/kxonAexj)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was actually the `count($myhours)` that was causing the problem. Basically even with an empty string it still returns an array with 1 element. Changed to check if `count($myhours) > 1` and everything is working as expected:

```
<?php
$myhours = explode(",", substr($arruser['arhours'],0,strlen($arruser['arhours']) - 1));
$checked = "";
for($hour = 0; $hour <= 23; $hour++) {
    if(count($myhours) > 1) {
        for($h = 0; $h <= count($myhours); $h++) {
            if((int)$hour == (int)$myhours[$h]) {
                $checked = " checked ";
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $checked = "";  
    }
    if(strlen($hour) == 1) {
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox " . $checked . " value=" . $hour . " onchange=\"updatehour(" . $_REQUEST['user'] . ",this.checked, '" . $hour . "')\">0$hour:00</td>";   
    } else {
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox " . $checked . " value=" . $hour . " onchange=\"updatehour(" . $_REQUEST['user'] . ",this.checked, '" . $hour . "')\">$hour:00</td>";
    }
    $checked = "";
}
?>
```